# pyspark: Generalize "for" statement in Lambda

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm calculating multiple features for a single column ("text") in a DF, i.e. number of numeric characters, number of alphanumeric characters...

Currently this is what I have:

```
def query_features(df):
    my_fx = sf.udf((lambda x: [sum(c.isdigit() for c in x),
                               sum(c.isalnum() is False and c is not " " for c in x)]
                   ), ArrayType(IntegerType()))

    df = df.withColumn("numeric", my_fx("text")[0])\
           .withColumn("non_numeric", my_fx("text")[1])

    return df
```

Since I want to iterate over the characters multiple times to calculate different features, is it possible to generalize the "for" statement (`for c in x`) inside the lambda function? Or is this already an ideal solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do only one for loop, then use the traditionnal `for` structure in a defined function (not a lambda - your current use case does not require a lambda):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

@F.udf(T.ArrayType(T.IntegerType()))
def my_udf(input_col):
    isdigit = 0
    isalnum = 0
    for c in input_col:
        isdigit += c.isdigit()
        isalnum += (c.isalnum() is False and c is not " ")
    return [isdigit , isalnum]
```